# How to avoid full table scan when MySQL optimizer opts out of using a key on a small joined table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm running into a strange issue and I'm not sure how to google the scenario properly. I have 2 tables supplied below:

```
CREATE TABLE revenue_centers (
 revc_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 revc_name varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (revc_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE cpt (
 cpt_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 cpt_revc_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (cpt_id),
 KEY cpt_revc_id (cpt_revc_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

There are more columns but the ones above are all that should be needed. These tables are duplicated across separate databases for several customers. Below is one of the queries I have that is causing me the issue:

`select * from cpt left join revenue_centers on cpt_revc_id=revc_id order by cpt_id;`

With EXPLAIN, on tables that have at least 4 rows in revenue_centers, we get the following:

```
 1  SIMPLE  cpt             index   PRIMARY         4                       89664
 1  SIMPLE  revenue_centers eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   _8.cpt.cpt_revc_id  1
```

The query is quick and there is no lag. For customers that don't use revenue_centers, we get the following:

```
 1  SIMPLE  cpt             ALL             22725   Using temporary; Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE  revenue_centers ALL  PRIMARY    1       Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

I understand that because the full scan of revenue_centers is likely cheaper than going through an index of 1, mysql chooses to go with the join buffer. I do not understand why it chooses to do the full scan on the cpt table.

If I use the FORCE INDEX hint on the join, it turns into an eq_ref type join and the cpt query no longer uses a temporary table or the filesort. If possible, I would like to avoid adding this into our code. I've attempted to set max_seeks_for_key as low as 1 to see if I could force the optimizer to use the primary key without the index hint but it refuses to change.

Aside from adding the FORCE INDEX to our codebase, is there any way I can improve this query or at least prevent the use of a temporary table?

Comment: @bill-karwin Thank-you for the formatting help.

Comment: `ORDER BY` optimizalisation requires multicolumn indexes. it's in the MySQL manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html .. So you need to create the index `cpt(cpt_revc_id, cpt_id)` to avoid " Using temporary; Using filesort"

Comment: You are saying that, in the slow case, there are zero rows in `revenue_centers`?

Comment: And...  How long does each query take?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Since this is InnoDB, that is effectively what the index has in it.

Comment: @RickJamesyes i missed you fact it was InnoDB engine which indeed has a copy of the PRIMARY KEY within secondary indexes

Comment: @rickjames correct, the join on the empty table is the slower query. Initially the query is roughly 10-15 seconds. When using force index primary, it drops to 400ms.